# How to achieve fullscreen editor on button click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullscreen

> I have a editor. I want to make it fullscreen on certain button click.

Actually I want to acheive CKEditor like maximize feature through jauery,

Please see this link:
http://ckeditor.com/demo

This demo maximize button is there. I want to achieve same using jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Besides from appending (and removing) a CSS class on it when a button is clicked with JavaScript, you can also use a few CSS tricks:

```css
#full-screen-toggler:checked ~ #youreditor {
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0px;
}

#youreditor #fslabel::after {
  content: "enter fullscreen";
  cursor: pointer; /* optional */
}

#full-screen-toggler:checked ~ #youreditor #fslabel::after {
  content: "exit full screen";
}

/* Styles for preview */
#youreditor { background: green; padding: 10px; }
#youreditor #fslabel::after { color: white; padding: 3px 5px;
  border-radius: 2px; border: 1px groove white; }
```

```html
<input id="full-screen-toggler" type="checkbox" style="display: none;" />
<div id="youreditor">
  <label id="fslabel" onclick="" for="full-screen-toggler" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/42/)**

You could acheive that using custom css class :

```
.full-screen{
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$('#maximize').on('click', function(){
    $('#container').toggleClass('full-screen');
})
```

```css
    .full-screen{
        z-index: 9999;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    div{
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      background-color:green;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'>
  <button id='maximize'>[]</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any plugin.. for smooth max and min editor like CKEditor..?

Comment: CKEditor also add a class for this purpose called `cke_maximized` plus some extra style.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the user window's dimension to container, by window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight

css:

```
.container { width:200px; height:100px; background:#ccc; }
```

html:

```
<div class='container'>
    <button class='maximize'>Maximize</button>
    <button class='minimize'>Minimize</button>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$('.maximize').on('click', function(){
    $('.container').css({'width': window.innerWidth, 'height': window.innerHeight});
});
$('.minimize').on('click', function(){
    $('.container').css({'width':'200px' , 'height': '100px'});
});
```

working example
link: http://jsbin.com/raduqihibo/edit?html,css,js,output